# twilio receive sms post double

Tags: vb.net, sms, twilio

When receiving an sms from Twilio back to my page the POST variables containing the information twice.

The page that Twilio calls greps the parameters as following:

```
Dim smsFROM = Page.Request.QueryString("From") 'User number
Dim smsTO = Page.Request.QueryString("To") 'Twilio numer
Dim smsBODY = Page.Request.QueryString("Body")
```

But the parameters all have the information twice:

For example the body: "This is a test,This is test"

This is also with the phone numbers in the To and From field.

Anyone a clue what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio has released a new '[Request Inspector](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-can-i-debug-my-application)'. If you look under 'Logs' for your incoming SMS, you should be able to see the full HTTP request. Can you check to see if the parameters are doubled up there too? If so, you should probably get in touch with help@twilio.com...